# Section 8 Prejudice does not start

Tags: games-for-windows-live, section-8

I completed Section 8 Prejudice installation but when I run the game nothing happens. I uninstalled and re-installed Games for Windows Marketplace application and redistribution but the game still won't run. How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you start the game? Did you buy it through Steam?

Comment: @Drake There are no error messages when the game starts and nothing happens. No it is not a Steam game.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately sometimes Game for Windows Live could be a real pain. Try to check if there are any error messages when you launch the game.

The official forum has [a list of possible solutions](http://forums.timegate.com/showthread.php?t=20036) to most frequent problems. Point 8) could be related to your problem and hopefully will help you solve it.

> **8. Why am I receiving a "Games for Windows Live has failed to initialize" crash when launching the Prejudice™ PC?**
>
> Some users have reported an issue with Games for Windows - LIVE (GfWL)
>   causing Section 8 to crash on start-up with the message “Games for
>   Windows Live failed to initialize” or similar GfWL error messages.
>   These are most likely caused by an improper installation of GfWL, a
>   conflicting network setting, or conflicts with virus scanning
>   software.
>
> In order to resolve this issue, please try the following in order:
>
> - Uninstall GfWL (Note: You must uninstall both "Games for Windows - Live" and "Games for Windows - Live Redist")
>
>   - Vista: Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features
>   - XP: Go to Control Panel > Add Remove Programs
> - Navigate to your System folder (32-bit systems: C:\WINDOWS\system32 / 64-bit systems: C:\WINDOWS\system64) and make sure the following are
>     deleted from your PC:
>
>   - xlive folder
>   - xlive.dll
>   - xlive.dll.cat
>   - xlive.pdb
>   - xlivefnt.dll
> - Reinstall the latest version of GfWL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959445/en-us
> - Visit Microsoft’s GfWL FAQ: http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Support/Pages/ogctechnicalIssues.aspx
> - Contact LIVE support at 1-877-274-4349
> - Turn your anti-virus software off
> - Ensure your router is set-up properly as per GfWL: http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Support/Pages/ogctechnicalIssues.aspx

Comment: Tried point #8 and #19. Both didn't work for me.